# Desktop file not executing command

Tags: linux, terminal, mime-types, uri-scheme

I have this simple command to check if a file exists:

```
if [ -f /tmp/file.txt ] ; then echo "yes" ; else echo "no" ; fi
```

If I run it direcly on terminal, it works (shows "yes" if the file exists and "no" if it doesn't). But I want to execute this command inside a `.desktop` file using it as a value to `Exec` key:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Exec=if [ -f /tmp/file.txt ] ; then echo "yes" ; else echo "no" ; fi
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Categories=Utility;X-XFCE;X-Xfce-Toplevel;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/custom
Name=Custom Test
Comment=Custom
```

If I try to execute `xdg-open custom://` I get `custom://: error opening location: The specified location is not supported`, but if I change `Exec` value to `echo "yes"` and execute `xdg-open custom://`, it shows `yes` on terminal.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It probably doesn't run a shell. You can try it with `sh -c '...'` or preferably by putting the statement in a script and specifying that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to execute shell script coding in .desktop file which is not supported.

The reason why "echo yes" worked is .desktop executes the echo command with paramter as "yes" which is acceptable.

.desktop executes commands along with options and parameters. You can write the shell script code in a .sh file and mentioned it in Exec or Run the code using

```
Exec=sh -c "if [ -f /tmp/file.txt ] ; then echo 'yes' ; else echo 'no' ; fi"
```

Here .desktop executes "sh" with options and params

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your Exec to:

```
bash -c 'if [ -f /tmp/file.txt ] ; then echo "yes" ; else echo "no" ; fi'
```

The 'if' command is a bash-builtin, not an external command.